How to connect cardano-db-sync to cardano node running on private cardano network?
After trying to connect cardano-db-sync to a cardano node running on a private cardano network, we are encountering multiple errors regarding the config files used. For example, missing keys in the config file and this error: cardano-db-sync: Error SNErrDefault: "insertValidateGenesisDist: Genesis data mismatch."
Could you help me understand if the errors I'm encountering stem from misconfigured config files or from using incompatible versions of cardano node and cardano db sync?
I am running a cardano node which was setup by following steps 1, 2 and 3 of the README.md file of this repo: https://github.com/mostafachegeni/UZH-Cardano-Network
Then, I cloned the cardano-foundation/cardano-graphql (https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-graphql) repo and tried to run it using the docker-compose.yml file by doing the following adjustments:

commenting the service which runs the cardano-node-ogmios
modifying the socket path to point to our node's socket file
loaded a volume with our node's config files, like config.json, dbsync.json, topology.json, alonzo-genesis.json, etc.
generated the genesis file hashes and added the appropriate keys to the dbsync.json file

We have tried using the following different cardano-db-sync image versions:

13.2.0.1
sancho-4-2-1

